# border radius ie firefox chrome conflicts

Tags: internet-explorer, css

I have a conflicts in css3 border radius between browsers.

```
#menu ul li:first-child {
    border-radius: 0px 8px 8px 0px;
}

#menu ul li:last-child {
    border-radius: 8px 0px 0px 8px;
}

<ul>
    <li><a href="#">الرئيسية</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">صفحتي</a></li>            
    <li><a href="#">كتبي</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">أصدقائي</a></li>            
    <li><a href="#">خروج</a></li>
</ul>
```

firefox

[image: FireFox and Chrome]

ie problem

[image: IE Problem]

Comment: please use "pie"  , it will take all browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm suspecting it's because of the rtl direction.

**Solution**: add a class to your HTML for IE using conditionals - example:

```
<!--[if IE]><div dir="rtl" class="ie"><![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!--><div dir="rtl"><!--<![endif]-->
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">الرئيسية</a></li><li><a href="#">صفحتي</a></li><li><a href="#">كتبي</a></li><li><a href="#">أصدقائي</a></li><li><a href="#">خروج</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

I've added the class to a containing div, but you can add it directly to the `<html>` tag (see http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/ )

And then you'll have something like this in your CSS:

```
#menu li:first-child {
    border-radius: 0 8px 8px 0;
}
#menu li:last-child {
    border-radius: 8px 0 0 8px;
}
.ie #menu li:first-child {
    border-radius: 8px 0 0 8px;
}
.ie #menu li:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 8px 8px 0;
}
```

Full demo here http://dabblet.com/gist/2774749 - I've tested it and works the same in Chrome, Firefox, Opera and IE9.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#menu ul li:first-child {
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 8px;
    border-top-left-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
}

#menu ul li:last-child {
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 8px;
    border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
}
```

it's always better to define you browser-specific css before you do the general command

Comment: same problem , fixed in ie but thing goes wrong in firefox and chrome .

Comment: could use this fix with conditional comments and only load it for IE?

Comment: try to add your css at the end of my css

Answer (score -1):

in ie border radius not supported via CSS you have to use Javascript 
Read this tutorial for complete help how to border radius in IE

http://davidwalsh.name/css-rounded-corners